# a question about solving recurrence with constant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, constants

Solve ${x_n}^2sin(\theta)={d^2-\frac{|x_{n-1}-x_{n+1}|}4}^2{} \& x_{n+1}=x_ncos(\theta)\pm \sqrt{{x_n}^2(cos^2(\theta)+1)-d^2}$

--I am really confused about howcan I deal with the constant term. If there is not this constant d then I can solve this easily, but this constant really prevent me from doing most of the things I have learnt. I tried to substitute $x_{n}$ with other variable to neglect this constant term, but my attempts failed. Is there a way to deal with this constant term? Thank you..

Comment: Two solutions: $x_n = \pm d/\sqrt{\sin(\theta)}$.  I don't know if there are other closed-form solutions.

Comment: Um may I ask how did you deal with the constant? Is there some resource I could learn here? Thank you

Comment: Oh, also $x_n = \pm (-1)^n d/\sqrt{\sin(\theta)}$.

Comment: It's not really "dealing with the constant", rather making the $|x_{n-1}-x_{n+1}|^2/4 = 0$.

Comment: sorry I don't quite understand this-- what is the though process under this? I tested this and it is indeed true

Comment: Why have you added a second question without explanation ?

Comment: Sorry forgot about that. This is actually a geometry problem and I am taking an algebraic approach-- I just discovered a law of cosine I could use

Comment: There are two recurrences in the question. Should both of them hold for the same sequence $\{x_n\}$ or for each recurrence an individual satisfied sequence should be found? Which are initial values of $x_n$, that is $x_1$ or $x_0$?